# Does Lasso 8.6 have a means of extracting an uploaded zip file to a specified path?

Tags: lasso-lang

I am trying to provide a means of allowing people to upload zips and have them extracted to a particular file path. It seems like zip functionality has been added in Lasso 9 but I'm curious if there is in fact a method for doing this in 8.6 or if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options (besides upgrading to 9):

1. First, you could use [os_process] to call the unzip command-line utility and have it do it for you
2. In 8.5, there was an example for the LJAPI documentation that created a [zip] custom type that you should be able to use. (I'm not sure if the 8.6 installer has it, but for OS X, after installing 8.5 you could find it here: /Applications/Lasso Professional 8/Documentation/3 - Language Guide/Examples/LJAPI/Tags/ZipType/) Chapter 67 of the Language Guide has documentation on how to get it installed and working.

Answer (score 0):

Further expounding option 1 in bfad's answer: You might like the Lasso 8 [shell](http://www.lassosoft.com/tagswap/detail/shell) tag from TagSwap to make this even easier. Here's an example where I extract tar'd and gzip'd archives:

```
// authenticate with user that has file permissions in this directory
inline(-username='username', -password='password');

    // load shell tag from TagSwap
    library_once('shell.inc');

    // call tar  from bash shell
    shell('tar -zxf myfile.tgz');

/inline;
```